# How can I simply include opencv INSIDE my project with CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I would like to use opencv inside my project folder because my other colleagues are not all working on the same platform (Linux, Windows). So to make it easier to clone and compile the project, I would like to have only to make a clone git and launch the compilation to be able to work on the project. (without any use of environnement variable, to be totaly independent)

As with other libraries (glfw), I simply added the unzipped folder inside my dependencies folder. Then I added the add_subdirectory and target_link_libraries statements.

Then I get a small error that I can't solve.

**Information about my project below**

**1. Project folder structure**

```
project
│   README.md
|   CMakeLists.txt                (my CMakeLists project)    
└───dependencies
│   └───opencv-4.1.2
│       │   CMakeLists.txt        (the original opencv CMakeLists (untouched))
│       │   ...
└───src
    │   main.cpp
```

**2. my CMakeLists content**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(OpTests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(dependencies/opencv-4.1.2)

add_executable(OpTests src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OpTests opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_videoio)
```

**3. main.cpp content**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main() {
    std::cout << CV_VERSION << std::endl;
    cv::Mat M(2,2, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
    std::cout << "M = " << std::endl << " " << M << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**4. The error**

```
°
°
°
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jeremy/CLionProjects/OpTests/cmake-build-debug
[  3%] Built target ittnotify
[  9%] Built target ippiw
[ 18%] Built target libjasper
[ 45%] Built target libwebp
[ 69%] Built target opencv_core
[ 90%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 93%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 96%] Built target opencv_videoio
[100%] Built target opencv_highgui
Scanning dependencies of target OpTests
[100%] Linking CXX executable bin/OpTests
CMakeFiles/OpTests.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:664: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/OpTests.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:672: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/OpTests.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'bin/OpTests' failed
make[3]: *** [bin/OpTests] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OpTests.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpTests.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:88: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/OpTests.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/OpTests.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:186: recipe for target 'OpTests' failed
make: *** [OpTests] Error 2
```

**So 3 questions:**

What did I do wrong? 
And is it possible to simply fix it without a 100 lines CMakeLists?

Is this a bad practice?

Thank you in advance

Beautiful day

Comment: Smells like **incompatibility** of your system OpenCV headers (`/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp`) and OpenCV you building.

Comment: Yet these are the headers of the cloned file. Thank you for the research proposal, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know the preferred way is to install OpenCV and then require it.

Therefore clone the repo of OpenCV, build and install it:

```
git clone git@github.com:opencv/opencv.git
cd opencv
make -j8
sudo make install
```

This can also be achieved by using a pre-build package from a package manager...

Then you can use the library in cmake via:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(OpTests)

find_package(OpenCV 4.2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(OpTests src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OpTests PRIVATE
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
target_compile_features(OpTests PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

Note that the library can be required using `find_package` and added as a dependency using the `target_link_libraries` command.
Also note that you should set the c++ version using `target_compile_features`.
To get a better understanding of cmake you can refer to the talk of Daniel Pfeifer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsXLMQ6WgIk.

Comment: I was trying to follow your instructions on Ubuntu 22.04. But if I try to clone from `git@github`, it is returning error `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`. If I clone using `https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git` then make -j8 returns error, `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: 1. probably you have not setup your ssh key 2. did you cd into the directory?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not setup the ssh on linux yet. However, I found simple sudo apt-get command working fine.

Comment: "This can also be achieved by using a pre-build package from a package manager..." - apt is a package manager.

Comment: Just out of completeness. Nowadays you should probably use conan to get more reproducable builds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux (I tried on Ubuntu 22.04), you can do it even easier way.

1. go to terminal and install opencv `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`
2. in cmake use similar as @Arwed Mett instructed:

```js
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(OpTests)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(OpTests src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(OpTests PRIVATE
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
#target_compile_features(OpTests PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

It should work.

Comment: Actually by using a prebuild package from a package manager I meant what you suggested. But not every Linux distro uses apt. Eg. arch linux uses pacman. There are also some you can use on any distro, but the list is long.